# Gradle dependency scopes

Tags: maven, gradle, parent-pom

I was experimenting a little bit with Gradle but as mainly being a Maven user, some dependency scopes are confusing me …

Some are identical to Maven:

```
compile -> compile
runtime -> runtime
compileOnly -> provided
```

but I also encounter `implementation` which sounds like the `parent` element of Maven POM but then again also not.

Can somebody explain me what is `implementation` and some other if they exist and I didn’t mention here (test versions of above are clear no need to explain)?

And if `implementation` is not like parent on Maven, how can we have the parent POM effect of Maven in Gradle?

Comment: compile and runtime are deprecated. The dependencies are explained in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As commented, please have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) or even at [this recent webcast](https://gradle.com/blog/dependency-management-with-gradle-fundamentals/) (disclaimer: I am co-presenting that webcast)

As for the Maven comparison, view migrating / learning from Maven to Gradle the same as moving from subversion to git: while some vocabulary is the same, understanding the model of the later helps more than comparing.

In short:

- Do not use `compile` or `runtime` in Gradle, they are deprecated.
- `implementation` relates to dependencies that are required to compile and run your application.
- `compileOnly` and `runtimeOnly` should be self-explanatory in the context of the above
- The `java-library` plugin adds the `api` configuration which is reserved for dependencies that consumers of your library will need to *compile*.

There is no direct equivalent to a Maven parent pom. Whether you are talking about plugins, build config or dependencies, the way to centralize are different. Have a look at the documentation on [multi-project authoring](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Comment: don't know why this answer got downgraded to -2 but it was useful to me. +1

Comment: then what 'api' does?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/1.2.0.RELEASE, it's showing 'compile'. Does it mean it will only require in compile time, then it will convert to byte code and not required in runtime?

Comment: No it means it is required for compilation, and that implies at runtime as well.

Comment: add id 'java-library' then with 'api' define depency will work:)

Comment: "`compileOnly` and `runtimeOnly` should be self-explanatory in the context of the above".  I'm not sure I follow.  They're self-explanatory in the context of the above documentation, the above video, the above statement that says "Do not use `compile` or `runtime` in Gradle, they are deprecated.", or the above statement that says "`implementation` relates to dependencies that are required to compile and run your application"?